# Killing Like Task Manager

Tags: python, ms-word, pid

Inside Task Manager [Windows 8+], in the "Processes" tab it lists all the processes currently running. If we open 2 windows of MS Word, it will only appear once, however this is actually a group and can be expanded to be able to see and end both tasks separately.

This is great, however it DOES NOT carry over to the "Details" tab where WINWORD.EXE is listed but only 1 occurrence! And thus only 1 PID! Sharing a PID is an issue because an attempt to close it results in the entire thingbeing closed.

I want to only kill a specific word window, not ALL word windows which has been happening when I try to kill windows programatically (currently i'm using `taskkill` through an `import os` in python, any other way to do it without additional modules would be alright as well).

Right now when I run `taskkill.... "WordDoc.docx"` it kills every open word document which is extremely annoying and potentially data losing. Is there a way to be able to kill "proccesses" like how it is done in task manager?

Thank you

PS I am not using /T so that is not the issue

Answer (score 1):

When closing a single window of a process on the *Process* tab, Task Manager does not kill the process the window belongs to, but just sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to that window. You will notice that the Word window is not "killed" as you will still get a prompt to save and unsaved changes in your Word document.

You can do the same as Task Manager using the following code, which enumerates all top-level windows, and then sends WM_CLOSE if the window title matches a desired value:

```
import win32gui

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'My Word Document' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

Comment: anyway to use usually preloaded modules instead tho? (i appreciate your answer, but it would be better if i could use something that is installed with python, even if it is OS dependatn like os.ETC(). Thank you for your time

Comment: pst you should also import win32con, cause ur code doesnt work ;), but i would still like a native solution, its just for others :)